# How to edit parameters sent through a form on the Firebug console?

Tags: firefox, forms, firebug, json

When you sent data over a form, you can see what exactly you sent if you see the logs on the Firebug console. It also gives you an option to resend the data. Is there is a way to edit that data within Firebug to send something different? If not, I would like to know if there is any other tool that can.

This is an example of what I see on Firebug console after having sent a certain form:

```
Params Headers Post Response JSON
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded  Do not sort
[action]
save
[user name]
Someuser
[Source]
action=save&username=Someuser
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such option in Firebug, but the [Firefox built-in DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) allow you to edit the data of a previous request and send it again.

[image: *Edit and Resend* option in Firefox DevTools]

To get there, first select the *Network* panel, then in there a request.
When you click on the *Edit and Resend* button, you'll be able to edit everything, the request method, the URL, the query string, the headers and the body.

[image: Editing network request data in Firefox DevTools]

After a click on *Send* the request is sent to the server.

Comment: Send  not working

Comment: If you mean that you don't see the request within the request list after you clicked the *Send* button, ensure that the request filter is set to *All* and that the filter field at the top right is empty. If that doesn't work, try it in a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).