# Firefox update the page through 'Edit and Resend' request

Tags: firefox

I am trying using the 'Edit and Resend' feature of the developer console but its behavior is kind of counter intuitive.

I expected to be able to modify the parameters, resend the request, and see the actual new page received. Firefox indeed creates the new modified request, and I can copy it in curl format which is pretty useful, however, I can't seem to get it showing the new page it would receive.

Is there a way to update the currently displayed webpage with the newly received page?

ps: I am aware of this [How to edit parameters sent through a form on the Firebug console?](https://superuser.com/questions/1112057/how-to-edit-parameters-sent-through-a-form-on-the-firebug-console) but it doesn't address my problem

Comment: This is probably not universal so I'll just give my experience in a comment. Edit and Resend does indeed give new pages when the server does not request no-cache. But when it does firefox will not load it leaving the previously loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest this would not be a trivial thing for Mozilla to implement.

When you edit and resend the request, the web app itself has no knowledge of your actions. It is the same as if you were to copy the request as a `curl` command, go to your terminal, and make the request there.

To update what's rendered, you would somehow have to tell the web-app to update its state to reflect the newly fetched data. It might be something Mozilla want to add, but I can't really see it being possible because it would require the browser to re-invoke the code that processed the request in the first place.

To achieve what you want, you would probably need to actually intercept the original request and modify it. There are lots of proxy tools out there that allow you to achieve this:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-can-i-intercept-and-modify-http-requests